# Using Ruby to fuzz FTP Server

Tags: ruby, buffer-overflow, fuzzing

Hey, I'm new to Ruby and trying to learn by porting some progs from one language to another.  Right now I'm working on an FTP fuzzer in Ruby that mirrors this perl script:

```
use Net::FTP;
$target = "192.168.37.128";
$buffer = "A\x20";
$buffer .= "A" x 512;
$ftp = Net::FTP->new($target, Debug => 0, Timeout => 5)
      or die "Cannot connect to $host: $@ \n";
$ftp->login("anonymous",'anonymous@nowhere.com')
      or die "Couldn't log in: $@\n";
$ftp->list($buffer);
$ftp->quit;
```

This is my Ruby equivalent:

```
require 'net/ftp'
buffer = 'A\x20'
buffer = (buffer + ('A'*512))
ftp = Net::FTP.open('127.0.0.1','anonymous','anonymous')
ftp.login
ftp.list(buffer)
ftp.quit
```

When I run the program I get the following error:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:241:in `readline': end of file reached (EOF
Error)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:241:in `getline'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:251:in `getmultiline'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:265:in `getresp'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:281:in `voidresp'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:304:in `block in voidcmd'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:302:in `voidcmd'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:155:in `send_type_command'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:149:in `binary='
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:168:in `ensure in with_binary'

        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:168:in `with_binary'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:440:in `block in retrlines'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:439:in `retrlines'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:682:in `list'
        from ftpcrash.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

I've traced the issue to the `ftp.list(buffer)` line, but can't come up with a Ruby solution that will accomplish what `$ftp->list($buffer)` does in the perl one.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer is  unnecessary.  #list takes an optional argument like '*n', not a buffer, and it returns an array.

```
require 'net/ftp'
ftp = Net::FTP.open('ftp.gnu.org','anonymous','')
puts ftp.list
ftp.quit
```

Comment: Thoughts on a substitute?  The vulnerability that I'm fuzzing has to do with too many chars being passed in the ftp LIST command

Comment: Oh, then by all means do ftp.list("a_long_string") and rescue the error like @Zepplock suggests.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how will rescuing the error help if the list() method isn't built for what I'm trying to use it for?  Are you saying there is a way to 'force' the command to work through rescue?  Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: Nm, figured it out.  Thx @Zepplock for the original suggestion and @steenslag for being patient.  

Here is the result: 
'begin'
'rescue Net::FTPError $stderr.print "Done..., but shouldn't see\n"'

Comment: Got it figured out! THX @steenslag & @Zepplock

`begin`
`ftp.list(buffer)`
`rescue Net::FTPError`
`$stderr.print "Done...\n"`
`end`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by `net/ftp.rb` source code this exception is raised when ftp library is trying to get a response from the server and response is empty.

You should wrap this command in `begin/rescue/end` (or just `rescue`) and handle the error accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here What you want dude

```
#!/bin/ruby 

require 'socket'


buffer = "A" * 512

host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
port = 21
s = TCPSocket.open(host, port)
s.recv(1024)
s.send("USER anonymous\r\n", 0)
s.recv(1024)
s.send("PASS anonymous\r\n", 0)
s.recv(1024)
s.send(buffer + "\r\n", 0)
sleep 0.3
s.close
```

Stay Secure ;)